# Set column to automatically pull data from referenced table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have one column called 'speeding' in a table containing many other columns. This column contains an integer that is foreign key to an entry on a table named Speeding. This table has columns 1-25 and an id that is referenced by the 'speeding' column from the first table.

Besides using join, is there any setting I can set on 'speeding' to make it automatically pull the associated data from the table Speeding?

Comment: what's wrong with a join? its the best method

Comment: Do you use some sort of ORM data mapper? If not SQL JOIN is what you need

Comment: if you don't want to use join, you need to use multiple separate queries to get info between tables or denormalize your database, which any of those it's NOT recommended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a view, a view is basically a SQL statement that is stored on the MySQL server and acts like a table

```
CREATE VIEW ViewName AS
SELECT tbl1.data, tbl2.speeding
FROM tbl1
INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl2.key = tbl1.key;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html

You then use the view as you would use any table

```
SELECT data, speeding
FROM ViewName
```

Comment: but does give him that "magic" he was looking for and a good thing to know about.

Comment: Lol yea @Dagon is right (nice name btw) but this is essentially what I was looking for. I normally just use some classes to write all the sql statements bc i never remember the syntax. This will work perfectly.